# how to get value of a field which set on $(document).ready function?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm currently setting a textbox value by JavaScript. But when I try to get that value with.

```
$("#idField").val(), i get null value.
```

How I'm supposed to get those textbox values?

What I want to do is [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/g3vng/1/).

Comment: That *should* work, what's your HTML for the relevant input? What's the jQuery that assigns the value? Is it correctly/succesfully assigned?

Comment: i call jquery autocomplete function on document ready, which response to onclick action. the field successly assigned. the problem is i try to get those value which set by jquery autocomplete outside onready function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you #idField exists (unique ID)

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only works with input/select/textarea elements, if you want text just use .text(), if you want html just use .html();

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var user_name = $('#user_name').val();

        alert(user_name);
    });
</script>
<label for="user_name">Label</label>
<input type="text" name="user[name]" value="User name" id="user_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure that jQuery library is included properly.
- Make confirm that you're trying to access the `textfield` value after assigning some value to it, not before assign.
- ***Make sure that your `ID` is unique.***
- To set value to `textfield` syntax is: `$("#idField").val('some value')`.
- After set the you can get value.
- If you're trying to assign the value using any `variable`, check that the `variable` has some value or it is `null`. To set value using variable:

  ```
  var myVar = 'some value';
  $("#idField").val( myVar );
  ```
- Try to use firebug/ such like debugger to catch the error (if you don't get any luck)

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` with no parameters gets the value of the field at the time the function is called, but if your "#idField" element hasn't even been parsed yet then `$("#idField")` won't find it and then `.val()` will be `undefined`. This is why you need to run script that manipulates the DOM in a document ready handler or a script block at the end of the body.

In the case of your fiddle it's really not clear what you're trying to do, but you are declaring and initialising your `field_one_val` variable:

```
var field_one_val = $("#field_one").val();
```

...on page load at which time the field actually is empty so `field_one_val` ends up as an empty string.

Then within your click handler you use that variable:

```
$("#field_two").val('val '+field_one_val +' added to this field');
```

...but it is still an empty string.

**If what you are trying to do is on click of the second field get the value of the first field at that moment then do this:**

```
$("#field_two").val('val ' + $("#field_one").val() + ' added to this field');
```

As shown in this updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g3vng/2/

Comment: the real problem is how i assign the `field_one` value to variable `field_one_val`, so i can use that parameter as ajax post or get data.

Comment: Assign the variable within the same function that does your Ajax post/get, immediately before the Ajax call. As I said above, you need to get the `.val()` _at the time_, not assign it to a variable once on page load.